# Can someone explain the following method that is used to find the length of the repeating cycle or period of a repeating decimal?

Tags: java, algorithm, repeat

After reading information off the Wikipedia page for repeating decimals, I have found a way to find the number of digits in the repeating part of a decimal.

For example,

1/3 = 0.333333333333333333333333333333... so the result is 1 digit.

1/7 = 0.142857142857142857142857142857... so the result is 6 digits.

However, my method (in Java) did not work for 1/6 which should yield 1 because:

1/6 = 0.1666... so the result is 1 digit despite the non-repeating part of the decimal.

I have found a solution that works (credit to Nayuki Minase).

```
private static int getCycleLength(int n)
{
    Map<Integer,Integer> stateToIter = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    int state = 1;
    int iter = 0;
    while (!stateToIter.containsKey(state))
    {
        stateToIter.put(state, iter);
        state = state * 10 % n;
        iter++;
    }
    System.out.println(iter + " - " + stateToIter.get(state));
    return iter - stateToIter.get(state);
}
```

Can someone please explain to me how this algorithm works? Thank you.

Comment: 1/6 works perfectly fine to me. However, terminating decimals also return 1, since they can be represented with repeating zeroes. I suppose it's up to you to decide whether the method should return 0 or 1 in those cases.

Comment: It works fine, yes, because the solution I posted is the working one that I found. My question is asking for some kind soul to hold my hand and go through the logic behind this method.

Comment: @ChrisZhang I would step through the code in a debugger and see exactly what each line does.  Is there any line of code which causes particular concern, or it all baffling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nayuki here. The code is from Project Euler [p026.java](https://github.com/nayuki/Project-Euler-solutions/blob/master/p026.java). Let me explain what's going on.

The main idea is that we simulate **long division** and detect when the remainder starts repeating. Let's illustrate with an example of computing 1/7.

```
    0.142857...
  -------------
7 | 1.000000000
      7
    ---
      30
      28
      --
       20
       14
       --
        60
        56
        --
         40
         35
         --
          50
          49
          --
           10
           ...
```

---

To perform long division, we perform these steps:

1. Set divisor = 7. Set dividend = 1. (We are computing 1/7.)

   ```
     ----
   7 | 1
   ```
2. How many times does the divisor go into the dividend? Let this be *k*. Append this digit to the quotient.

   ```
       0
     ---
   7 | 1
   ```
3. Subtract *k* × divisor from the dividend. This is the remainder.

   ```
       0
     ---
   7 | 1
      -0
      --
       1
   ```
4. Shift in a new digit on the right side. In our case, it's an infinite decimal of zeros. This is equivalent to multiplying the dividend by 10.

   ```
       0
     ---
   7 | 1.0
      -0
      --
       10
   ```
5. Go to step 2 and repeat infinitely.

   ```
       0.1
     -----
   7 | 1.0
      -0
      --
       10
       -7
       --
        3
        ...
   ```

We update the dividend in every iteration of long division. If the dividend takes on a value that it previously did, then it will generate the same decimal digits.

Now, in code:

```
// Step 1
int divisor = 7;
int dividend = 1;

while (true) {
  // Step 2
  int k = dividend / divisor;  // Floor

  // Step 3
  dividend -= k * divisor;

  // Step 4
  dividend *= 10;
}
```

With a bit of math, steps 2 and 3 can be combined as `dividend %= divisor;`. Furthermore, this can be combined with step 4 to get `dividend = dividend % divisor * 10;`.

---

The map keeps track of the first time each dividend state was seen. In our example:

- The remainder 1 was seen at iteration 0.
- The remainder 3 was seen at iteration 1.
- The remainder 2 was seen at iteration 2.
- The remainder 6 was seen at iteration 3.
- The remainder 4 was seen at iteration 4.
- The remainder 5 was seen at iteration 5.
- The remainder 1 was seen at iteration 6.

The state at iteration 6 is the same as the state at iteration 0. Furthermore, this is the shortest cycle. Hence, the cycle length is 6 − 0 = 6.

Answer (score 1):

So in this algorithm this line is the key.

```
while(!stateToIter.containsKey(state))
```

It is breaking the program when it found a repetitive state. Now finding a repetitive state means we are detecting a repeating cycle. Lets go through the problem, say we have to find out for 6.
The way we do 1 / 6 is

```
Problem :6 | 1 | Result = ?  
 Step 1: 
 Add 0. in the result and multiply 1 with 10
 6 | 10 | 0.

 Iteration 

 Step 2: 
 Do the division
 6 | 10 | 0.1
      6
    -----
      4 [Mod]

 Iteration = 0

 Step 3: 
 Multiply mod with 10 and carry on
 6 | 10 | 0.16
      6
    -----
      40 
      36
    -----
      04 [Mod]


 Iteration = 1

 Now we find a repeating mod so now matter how far we go we always get 4 as mod and our result will be 0.166666.. and so on so our repeating cycle will be 1 which is our iteration.
```

Answer (score 0):

When conventing to decimal you progressively multiply the value you have by 10 until you either have 0 (no more to write) or give up (you have reached the limit of your precision)

Once you have the same value you are working on again, you will repeat the same digits from that point.  What the method does is find when you get a repeating values and computes how long it have been since you first saw it (the length of the repeating cycle)

---

BTW Another solution to this problem which avoids using a Map.  Any repeating sequence must be a multiple of 1/9 or 1/99 or 1/999 or 1/9999 etc.  This finds how many nines is required for the divisor to be a factor.  This is the point at which it repeats.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 3; i < 100; i++) {
        System.out.println("i: " + i + " f: " + 1.0 / i + " repeat: " + getRepeatingCount(i));
    }
}

public static final BigInteger TEN_TO_19 = BigInteger.TEN.pow(19);

public static int getRepeatingCount(int divisor) {
    if (divisor <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    while (divisor % 2 == 0) divisor /= 2;
    while (divisor % 5 == 0) divisor /= 5;
    int count = 1;
    if (divisor == 1) return 0;
    for (long l = 10; l > 0; l *= 10) {
        long nines = l - 1;
        if (nines % divisor == 0)
            return count;
        count++;
    }
    for(BigInteger bi = TEN_TO_19; ; bi = bi.multiply(BigInteger.TEN)) {
        BigInteger nines = bi.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
        if (nines.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(divisor)).equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
            return count;
        count++;
    }
}
```